# What is the reason for providing %s in the insert command while entering values into database using python pyscopg2

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sql-insert, psycopg2

I was trying to enter values into my database table in PostgreSQL, so I used the psycopg2 module.

The syntax I used is as follows:

```
Load_data= """

insert into stocks (Date, Symbol, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, Delivery, Delivery_percent)
values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);

"""
```

I'm calling this with my cursor.execute(Load_data) and conn.commit(). I was able to load the data, but I want to know the reason why am I supposed to provide %s in the values.

I'm unable to think of why it is required. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: is the syntax for  parameter ..each %s is a tag for a parameter

Comment: Thanks, @scaisEdge, can you please point me to any documentation? I was unable to find any.

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html  .. just google python postgresql binding

Comment: More on point [Parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries)

Answer (score 2):

The `%s` (or `%(var_name)s` if passing a dictionary of parameters) syntax represents a parameter to be filled with a value when the transaction is executed. This syntax allows `psycopg` to translate Python values to SQL values (e.g. `None` to `NULL`) which is pretty handy if you consider all the different types that need translation.

This syntax also allows for simpler notation when passing parameters to a query so that the same query text can be reused with different values. For example:

```py
def insert_row(name):
    query_text = "INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES (%s);"
    cursor.execute(query_text, [name]) # or cursor.execute(query_text, (name,))
```

Finally, and, in my opinion, most importantly, `psycopg` also sanitizes parameter values in order to avoid SQL injection attacks.

You might wonder why not just use string interpolation or concatenation to build the query string with the desired values, like this:

```py
def insert_row(name):
    query_text = f"INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('{name}');"
    cursor.execute(query_text)
```

This approach would work fine for most uses (especially as string translation doesn't require much effort), however what if the `name` comes from a user and that user provides a `name` value of  `"my_name'); DROP TABLE my_table;"`.

Then the interpolated `query_text` becomes `"INSERT INTO my_table (name) VALUES ('my_name'); DROP TABLE my_table;');"`. This will insert the string `'my_name'` as the `name` value and the delete the `my_table` table, which is probably something you want to avoid.

Using parameter notation here (`%s`) will cause the inserted name value to be the provided string (`"my_name'); DROP TABLE my_table;"`), rather than allowing that string to execute arbitrary SQL in the database.

[Relevant documentation](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Answer (score 0):

Each %s is a placeholder for one field of data.  You could argue that there needs to be one %s for each column you are inserting so that writing it explicitly is unnecessary, but that is not necessarily the case.  You might want to write your insert statement to hard-code some of the column values, or use PostgreSQL functions to derive some column values with no inputs from python, or one input, or more than one input.

```
 values (DEFAULT, %s, NULL, now(), sqrt(%s), tsrange(%s, %s), nextval('some_sequence'), 'cat')
```

That is just an example, it is unlikely you would want to do all of those things at the same time, but is likely you would want to do at least one of them.